# Add to Cart Button not working in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I am working on a WordPress project with woo-commerce integration in which there are two options to add a  product to cart. one is an add to cart button on product hover another is a button in the product details section. When we click on add to cart button displayed on hover product is added to the cart but on doing the same with the button on product detail page nothing happens.

The form in the details section sends no product details on explicitly adding the details too the product is not added.

Tried solving it using hard code too but unable to figure out the issue. any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the button on your product page clickable? I mean there may be some other element which may go over this and since blocking the click event. If this is the issue, you can fix this with some CSS z-index.

Comment: This sounds like a theme specific problem. Have you tried to update all components and change to storefront?

Comment: check by switching theme if the problem persist

Comment: yes thats clickable , can not be theme specific as it was initially working.